# Execute a PHP file, and return the result as a string

Tags: php, string

Let's assume I have the following file - `template.php`:

```
<?php $string = 'Hello World!'; ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?= $string; ?></h1>
        <p>You should see something above this line</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm aware that I can use `file_get_contents()` to get the contents of the file as a string, which I can then manipulate as I require. However, `file_get_contents()` doesn't execute PHP statements.

I have successfully used cURL to get access to the rendered version of the file, but it seems rather slow and clunky, adding quite a fair amount of time to the execution of the page - which I would imagine is due to a DNS lookup being performed.

So, how can I get the contents of `template.php` into a string - while having usable PHP there?

Comment: you mean file_get_contents() right?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ob_start();
include('template.php');
$returned = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Watch out though as since the file is being included & not executed on it's own you might get funny behaviour.

Comment: Including the file scans it and if there is PHP inside, it's executed like if called stand-alone. If that's not what you mean, then could you be more specific?

Comment: I think what he is trying to say is to be careful, if the php file you are executing has any side-effects it could mutate the state of your application even though it is not sending output to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to do this *within* PHP, you could execute a php script from the command line, and pipe it to a text file, like so:

```
php -f phpFile.php > output.html
```

Comment: While this isn't the right answer, it is definitely helpful to know in the future.