# Include PHP file as string

Tags: php, include

is it possible to make something like this?

```
// file.php
$string = require('otherfile.php');
echo $string;

// otherfile.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<?php require 'body.php';?>
</body>
</html>

// body.php
<p>Lorem ipsum something</p>
```

And get this output?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum something</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that code won't work, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683771/execute-a-php-file-and-return-the-result-as-a-string

Comment: This looks a bit like you are re-inventing templates. Maybe you can use a template engine?

Comment: I think template engines were re-inventing PHP but it's a matter of opinion :)

Comment: PHP is a template engine

Answer (score 66, accepted):

file.php

```
ob_start();
include 'otherfile.php';
$string = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: There is a parse() function on the PHP site at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php that adds error reporting and allows you to pass variables to the template file.

Comment: This solution is better than Mark Bakers - if you want to execute PHP code inside otherfile.php

Comment: This worked perfectly for me inside my wordpress plugin where I am calling up an include file within a shortcode. Thanks @SmokeyPHP

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks

Comment: Awesome and insane in equal parts!

Answer (score 15):

```
$string = file_get_contents('otherfile.php',TRUE);
echo $string
```

Use of the TRUE argument for file_get_contents() means it will search using the include path, like a normal include or require

Comment: If there is PHP in this file it's not going to be interpreted, you would need to use eval or something similar.

Comment: Manhim, I'm aware it would need evalling (or prettyfying if being echoed for display).... that was my reading of what OP wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Another cool thing to know, but SmokeyPHP's answer might be better:

```
<?php
$var = require 'myfile.php';
```

myfile.php:

```
<?php
return 'mystring';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a return statement in a file, and requires and includes will return the returned value, but you would have to modify the file to say something more like

```
<?php
    return '<p>Lorem ipsum something</p>';
?>
```

check example #5 under include documentation
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

I need a solution for Joomla and dompdf and I found this solution

```
ob_start();
require_once JPATH_COMPONENT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'file.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

only with require_once can use all functions from Joomla at the loaded script.
The file.php is a .html file renamed to .php and where added php code.