# Converting a response to string in PHP

Tags: php

Is there anyway to convert an html response to string in php. let me expalin through an example.

```
<?php
function printTitle($title="Welcome"){
?>
<div class='mainTitle'>
<div class='titleLogo'>

</div>
<div class='titleString'>
<?php echo $title; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Here calling this function anywhere will output html showing title.
Now what I need is to convert this response into string value so that it can be passed as json response like:

```
$response=array("title"=>printTitle(),"sidebar"=>getSideBar());

echo json_encode($response);
```

I want to do it like this so that I can fetch title and sidebar via ajax.

One way to do it is like:

```
<?php
    function printTitle($title="Welcome"){

    $ret="<div class='mainTitle'>
    <div class='titleLogo'>

    </div>
    <div class='titleString'>
    ". $title ."
    </div>
    </div>";

    return $ret;
    }
    ?>
```

but this makes html really a mess.

Comment: Use [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), like this: http://pastebin.com/jsjWuyuL

Comment: @DipeshParmar I am not talking about converting < or > to &lt; or &gt; I want to return the html response as string.

Comment: What do you get in the console when you use `console.log` in your JavaScript? You should, first of all, remove the line breaks. PHP won't parse this.

Comment: use a mvc framework so you don't have to write html and php mixed too much

Comment: EDIT: looks like I can comment after all ;)
I can't comment yet, so I'll post as an answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751182/include-php-file-as-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use output buffer:

```
function printTitle($title="Welcome"){
  ob_start();

  ...

  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Changed from ob_get_flush() to ob_get_clean();

Comment: This does not make sense, because he is not using `echo`, but initializes a string variable and returns it.

Comment: @Julian You need to read the question, not just skip it. This is a valid method that will do what the OP asked.

Comment: This answer makes perfect sense. However, [ob_get_clean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) may be a better choice.

Comment: @user2689155 I may be asking too much but can you please give an example, I tried what you told but not getting how to use it.

Comment: I tested your solution it is giving output two times

Comment: @manish it is outputting twice, because ob_get_flush flushes (outputs) the buffer as well as returning it. You want ob_get_clean, like webbiedave said.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
function printTitle($title="Welcome"){
    return <<<HTML
<div class='mainTitle'>
    <div class='titleLogo'>
    </div>
    <div class='titleString'>
    $title
    </div>
</div>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: @manish that is because you are outputting it to the browser directly. Use the view source option in your browser to see what it actually outputs, or use htmlentites() to view it in the browser.