# How to properly include a file when a string is needed?

Tags: php, silex

I have a local file that I need included in a beginning Silex application.  I just got started and I have all the boiler plate code setup - particularly here.

```
// I need to return test.php for this route
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->get('/', function() use($app) {
    return $string;  // put the file in a string
});
$app->run();
```

After some googling I found these articles: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751182/include-php-file-as-string), [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

So it looks like I can use `file_get_contents()` and if I need the code evaluated I could wrap it in `eval()`.  Or I could use the other method shown in the link.

I was hoping to just use something similar to `require()`, but Silex needs a string returned.  I imagine I could just write my own helper function `parseFile()` but this has to be done somewhere else already?

**Update**

```
// this does not work, I'v verified the path is correct.
return file_get_contents($path, TRUE);
```

Comment: Is the file static text or php code? Does it work if you return the contents with `new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(file_get_contents($path));`

Comment: currently it is static text, but I'm looking for a PHP solution long term - the file_get_contents() solution I noted does not work.  Why are you using `HttpFoundation`?  This is a local file.  I made the question more clear.

Comment: Silex uses HttpFoundation for requests/responses, and I believe when you just return a string from a controller, silex is just wrapping that in a HttpFoundation\Response. You could probably just create a subclass of Response that does the ob_get_contents thing in the constructor. Then you could just do something like `return new FileContentsResponse('path/to/file.php');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs are a bit hard to navigate but here they are with the appropriate anchor -

[Sensio Labs Documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#sending-a-file)

As you suggested there is a more direct way.

You basically need to use the aptly named `sendFile()` method.

```
$app->get('/files/{path}', function ($path) use ($app) {
    if (!file_exists('/base/path/' . $path)) {
        $app->abort(404);
    }

    return $app->sendFile('/base/path/' . $path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
ob_start();
require 'somefile.php';
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $contents;
```

Comment: Not sure if this would work and it's gross, but could you just `require 'somefile.php'; return '';`?