# Php variables in SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have php file with sql query, where are the php variables:

```
<?php
$request = "SELECT
sp.product_id AS $select_1,
sp.last_price AS $select_2,
sp.bu_key AS $select_3
  FROM $stamp.supplier_product sp 
  WHERE  sp.bu_key = '$country'
  AND sp.product_id IN ('$textarea_1') 
  AND to_timestamp('$startDate', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss.FF3') > sp.available_from_date
  AND (sp.available_thru_date > to_timestamp('$endDate', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss.FF3') OR sp.available_thru_date is NULL)
  AND sp.packaging_id = 'NO_PACKAGING'"; 
  ?>`
```

Also I have class with function, which call the content of the file:

```
class GetContent {     
private $directory;
private  $query_file;

public function __construct($directory, $query_file) 
{ 

$this->query_file = $query_file;    
$this->directory = $directory;
}      public function get_content($query_file)   
{   
     file_get_contents($query_file);
     $content = file_get_contents($query_file);
     echo nl2br( htmlspecialchars($content));  
} 
  public function include_file($query_file)   
{   include($query_file);
     var_dump($request);  
} }
```

and Call the class:

```
<?php
include('date_box.php');
$query_names = 'C:\\apache\\htdocs\\menue\\product\\queries';
$obj = new SelectOption($query_names);
$obj->get_diretory($query_names);
?>
```

My probles is: When I execute the query there are no variable, it can not to find them in my file. THis is the result of var_dump($request);

```
string(416) "SELECT sp.product_id AS , sp.last_price AS , sp.bu_key AS FROM
supplier_product sp WHERE sp.bu_key = '' AND sp.product_id IN ('') 
AND to_timestamp('', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss.FF3') > sp.available_from_date 
AND (sp.available_thru_date > to_timestamp('', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:mi:ss.FF3') 
OR sp.available_thru_date is NULL) AND sp.packaging_id = 'NO_PACKAGING'"
```

What I have to do for GET my variables from text?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify where the variables $select_1, $select_2, etc are being set?

Comment: $select_1, $select_2 are before the function with this file:

<?php
$select_1='something';
$select_2='something';
include('date_box.php');
$query_names = 'C:\\apache\\htdocs\\menue\\product\\queries';
$obj = new SelectOption($query_names);
$obj->get_diretory($query_names);
?>

Answer (score 1):

`include` directive is evaluating included file but in limited scope. When you're including file from inside a function, **only variables local to this function are accesible for included file**. And as you see:

```
public function include_file($query_file)   
{   include($query_file);
    var_dump($request);  
}
```

You have only one local variable here before including: `$query_file`.

I would recommend manual importing of variables to local scope. You can see some example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144260/925196