# php variables using phpmailer

Tags: php, include, phpmailer, file-get-contents

I'm trying to send a confirmation e-mail using phpmailer but stuck with a problem. 
The content of the mail is in a page called page_mail.php and I'm using php mailer to send this content but when I receive the e-mail it returns "1".

Can one of you help me ?

Here's my code

```
$req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='test@test.com'") or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array($req);

$body = include('page_mail.php');
    echo $body;

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSendmail();
$mail->AddAddress("test@test.com");
$mail->Subject = "MAIL TEST";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AltBody = "Ce message est au format HTML, votre messagerie n'accepte pas ce format.";
$mail->Send();

ini_get('sendmail_path');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use some output buffering techniques instead of `$body = include('page_mail.php');`. See example from [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

```
$string = get_include_contents('somefile.php');
```

Where `get_include_contents()` is defined as follows:

```
function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you intend to use some global variables in `page_mail.php` which are defined in your main PHP file, then I recommend using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144260/925196.