# Method with include isn't receiving variables

Tags: php

### The goal

Pass `$title` for my view `_Layout.phtml`.

### The scenario

**Home.phtml**

```
$title = 'My application';

[...]

MasterPage::Invoke('Layout');
```

**Layout.phtml**

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

**Invoke's method of `MasterPage`**

```
[...]

public static function Invoke($layout)
{
    include_once File::Get($layout)
}
```

### The problem

> Notice: Undefined variable: title in [...] on line 32

Comment: Probably scoping issue - when include is called within function, included variables won't be introduced to global scope. You can debug using var_dump(get_defined_vars()); - call it within your function and within global scope and see what is going on.

Comment: Seems like the variable doesn't exist in my function. In my `Home.phtml` I can see it and in `Layout.phtml` I just see the same error that I said before.

Answer (score 1):

Include directives are limited to variables in local scope, and **the only** variable in this scope:

```
public static function Invoke($layout)
{
    include_once File::Get($layout)
}
```

is `$layout`.

To "import" variables into this scope you can do something similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144260/925196