# variable scope being affected while using include_once

Tags: php, scope

```
    spl_autoload_register("auto");
    function auto($class_name){
        include_once($class_name.'.php');
    }

$url=new clean_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    $c=1;
    //echo $url->segment(2);
    if(!$url->segment($c)){
           //include homepage
    }
    else{
        switch($url->segment($c)){
            case 'events':
            include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/events.php');
            break;
            default:
            include_once('404.php');
            break;
        }
    }

?>
```

in the events.php file

```
<?php
if($url->segment($c+1)){
$e=$url->segment($c+1);
switch ($e) {
    case 'ecstasy':
        include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'temps/ecstasy.php');
        break;

    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
}
```

while testing the code on localhost(xampp) the code is working and the req. pages are being included.But when trying on the big rock server the output is coming as

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function segment() on a non-object in /home/public_html/events.php on line 2
```

What can be the reason for this difference and how can i make it work on the bigrock servers?

Comment: did you try `print_r($url);`?

Comment: `spl_autoload_register()` should throw exceptions when the autoload_function cannot be registered.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you did not include events.php somewhere else before these code blocks are even executed? As @KrishR mentioned, `spl_autoload_register` should have already thrown an error even before the `switch` statements.

Comment: on localhost its giving on using print_r:clean_url Object ( [path:clean_url:private] => /events )       but on server no output is coming

Comment: @Bez: the above code is in index.php file and the address i used was sitename.com/events/

Comment: after i add $url=new clean_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); in the events.php file at the top the server is giving Fatal error: Class 'clean_url' not found in /home/mechamjc/public_html/events.php on line 2 whereas

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this code works in XAMPP but the fatal error reported by Bigrock Servers is correct. You have error in your code, as `$url` **shouldn't be accessible from included file** because this variable and included file are in different scopes. All include directives are limited to their local scopes. Now some help: you can manually import variables before inclusion in many ways - for example use [extract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144260/925196) function.