# php: global variable mess

Tags: php, global-variables

Things got a little bit messy when trying to use a library I made. This is what my project looks like without the unnecessary content.

**lib_vars.php**

```
<?php $lib_var = 10;?>
```

**lib.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('lib_vars.php');
    function lib_func(){
        global $lib_var;
        echo $lib_var;
    }
?>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('lib/lib.php');
    function action(){
        lib_func();
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('action.php');
    function main(){
        if(true)
            action();
    }
    main();
?>
```

For some reason I have to place `require_once('action.php')` on top of `index.php`.
If I place it in the if-statement, It can't find `$lib_var` any more. If I have 10 different actions in `index.php`, than I would be forced to include 9 unnecessary files. Does someone know an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can't put it in the `if` statement. It wouldn't be a global variable there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to place `require_once('action.php')` on top of `index.php` but if you include anything within limited scope then you have to manually export all variables included by it as globals. Similarily, if you want to use global variables in included file, you have to "import" them. See example here of using `extract` to do such things: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144260/925196